# HERE Map is not loading (Javascript 3.1)

Tags: here-api

during the map initialization there is an error **Cannot read property 'version' of undefined**. Yesterday it was working like a charm. Any solution for it? I am using new Javascript API 3.1

```
 this.platform = new this.H.service.Platform({
     apikey: environment.hereMapApiKey_31,
     useHTTPS: true
 });
```

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
```

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
    at X.Ik (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:71), <anonymous>:44:738)
    at new X (eval at <anonymous> (mapsjs-core.js:71), <anonymous>:44:474)
    at HereMapService.initializeMap (hereMap.service.ts:23)
    at hereMap.component.ts:66
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:365)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:851
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:793)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:752)
    at zone-evergreen.js:854
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:570)
```

Comment: Are you sure this (environment.hereMapApiKey_31) is still working right?

Comment: @RaymondCamden yes, the value is there. On https://developer.here.com/projects/ the status of the apikey is set to **Enabled** and both values are the same. As I said, yesterday it was working fine. No code changes since yesterday on my site. I just generated second apikey, put it as a string (not variable) and the result is the same.

Comment: @RaymondCamden here you can find minimal reproducible. If you open DeveloperTools in Google Chrome then error will show up. plnkr.co/edit/Jc9OSuqJSIZ4cCxUz94i?p=preview 

I just noticed, that this error only occurs in Google Chrome. In Firefox it's working fine.

Comment: I can confirm, that today everything is working fine again. It was not working today at the morning but right now it seems, that problem just vanished. I don't know what happened in the meantime. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If it's solved, could you maybe close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a temporary problem and after couple of hours it just vanished. I can close the question.